# Life of Clara A. Walsh

Tags: japanese-language, clara-a-walsh

I am looking for any biographical information concerning Clara A. Walsh. She wrote "The Master-Singers of Japan," a selection of classical Japanese poetry translated into English. It was published in 1910 and reprinted in 1914 by John Murray.

Comment: *Master-Singers* has been [republished quite recently](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/26006988-the-master-singers-of-japan), including in kindle format. Unfortunately, neither Goodreads nor Wikipedia has any information on the author.

Comment: Also, someone has voted to close this question for the bizarre reason that it "currently includes multiple questions in one". Am I missing something? I'm voting to leave it open.

Comment: I like this question.  The front matter shows her living in Southsea in 1909.  I suppose she might be Clara Augusta Walsh, daughter of Frederick Henry Walsh, as shown on a 1911 census entry visible at https://www.geni.com/people/Frederick-Walsh/6000000025293773337 .

Comment: According to https://www.ancestry.com/genealogy/records/lady-augusta-annabella-chichester-24-hkvlg , CAW (1867-1924) was the daughter of Lady Augusta Annabella Chichester (1826-1914) and  Frederick Henry Walsh (1834-1921).

Answer (score 3):

An interim non-answer.

The only obvious internal clues in *The Master-Singers of Japan* about about the life of its author are its dedication to Professor H. J. Weintz, and the signature line at the end of the preface on p.19: "Clara A. Walsh / Southsea, 1909".
Southsea is part of Portsmouth, a city in the south of England.  This Weintz  was probably  the author in   of the Japanese grammar books published in 1904, reviewed in the [Journal of the Royal Asiatic Society](https://www.cambridge.org/core/journals/journal-of-the-royal-asiatic-society/article/abs/japanese-grammar-self-taught-by-h-j-weintz-marlborough-co-1904-japanese-grammar-by-h-j-weintz-hossfelds-series-hirschfeld-brothers-1904/99B864D5ABCC2C592AD2E1F1D908F491).

According to [*The History of British Women's Writing, 1880-1920: Volume Seven*](https://books.google.com/books?id=SJ43DQAAQBAJ&pg=PA179&lpg=PA179&dq=clara+augusta+walsh&source=bl&ots=FV1aiecejy&sig=ACfU3U2dJPBGIqlLGgx92O09IhwL9Q1bIQ&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjtsKzy_JzxAhVFvJ4KHUG7DEkQ6AEwEXoECBQQAw#v=onepage&q=clara%20augusta%20walsh&f=false)
(edited by Holly A. Laird), p.179, the author of *The Master-Singers of Japan* was Clara Augusta Walsh (1867-?).

A google search for "Clara Augusta Walsh" result in hits on genealogy web sites, and on works such as *Burke's Peerage*, showing that there was a Clara Augusta Walsh (1867-1924) living at her father's house, 51, Clarence Parade, Southsea.  She was the grand-daughter of the 4th Marquess of Donegall; her father had been a captain in the 78th Highlanders (or "Ross-shire Buffs") regiment in the British Army.

It seems reasonable to  guess that the author of *The Master-Singers* was Clara Augusta Walsh.  Her social status was more-or-less that of her approximate contemporary [Marianne North](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Marianne_North), who travelled alone to places like Borneo, California, and Japan as a botanical illustrator, so it is not impossible that CAW visited Japan, too.  Or, maybe she learned Japanese without leaving England, relying on Prof. Weintz's textbooks.